# Substitute to Html.BeginForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, view

Im using bootstrap to make a login view in my MVC 4 App. 
Its working but heres my login view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <link href="~/Content/dist/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Entrar</h2>
            <input type="text" id="User" name="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário"   required />
            <input type="password" id="Pass" name="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

But the reference of the css is the `'link href="~/Content/dist/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet'` line, but it only works if I remove the `@Html.BeginForm()`,  but then I can't get my action to be fired when I make a `HttpPost`.

How can I call my action without the `Html.BeginForm()` ?

Comment: Why don't you take that `link` element and put it outside of the form. You're better of putting it inside the `head` anyways.

Comment: @Kenneth i tried to put the link element outside the form, but then i get the boxes and button size changed. I need some way to the submit button knows where to go when it is pressed. Withoud the BeginForm method. The BeginForm changed the sizes of the forms and the button.

Comment: That has nothing to do with where the link element is. The reason for that is probably that your CSS has styles defined for elements when they're in a form (since your using bootstrap that is the case). You should modify your css so that it doesn't do that. You can't post a form without having a form.

Comment: I inspect the element and i get the form action = '/Account/LogIn?UserName=admin&Password=123456' with 1020 and 156 px. And the bootstrap elements are with 100% of width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see now that you're using two forms inside eachother. You should remove the bootstrap one and make sure the BeginForm emit the correct form:

```
    <link href="~/Content/dist/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("your-action", "your-controller", 
                               FormMethod.Post, 
                               new { @class="form-signin", role = "form} ))
        {
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Entrar</h2>
            <input type="text" id="User" name="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário"   required />
            <input type="password" id="Pass" name="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Mine too. I had exactly the same two forms situation.

Answer (score 1):

Move your link as indicated in the comments to the `<head>`, but resolve the `href` value like this:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dist/css/signin.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Sorry, it not works, the BeginForm is overrinding the bootstrap form class="form-signin" role="form"